# Does "printf" prevent deallocation of array?

Tags: c++, printf, dynamic-memory-allocation

I was putting together an example for how `new` can cause memory leaks, and why you should include a corresponding `delete`, when I found that my output depended on whether I included a call to `printf`:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>

class Foo {
  public:
    double* array;

    Foo(void) {
        array = new double[16];
        for (int i = 0; i < 16; ++i)
            array[i] = 5+i;
    }

    ~Foo() {
        delete[] array;
    }
};

void Bar(double** ptr) {
    Foo f;
    *ptr = f.array;

    // Expression in question:
    printf("ptr = %p\n", *ptr);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    double* ptr = NULL;
    Bar(&ptr);    
    printf("ptr[3] = %4.1f\n", ptr[3]);
    return 0;
}
```

Namely, if I leave in the expression `printf("ptr = %p\n", *ptr);`, then the output is

> ptr = 0x7fd7f44058d0
>
> ptr[3] =  8.0

but if I comment out that expression, then the output is

> ptr[3] =  0.0

So it seems like `printf` is managing memory behind the scenes somehow?

(I recognize that I shouldn't be peeking inside `ptr[3]` anyways, but I was just curious why this might be happening.)

Edit: Yes, the code would not be good, even if it didn't pursue undefined behavior; the goal here is was not to fix or prevent the problem, just to understand why it happened.
I think the answer to my question was just that the compiler is doing some stuff to be helpful, and that it gets different ideas depending on whether the `printf` is there

Comment: Undefined behaviour is undefined. Perhaps the compiler sees that `ptr[3]` is never accessed legally and optimizes out a bunch of code.

Comment: Since the mid 2000's you shouldn't use `new` either, you should use one of the smart pointer classes to ensure the pointers are deleted automatically. By now, `new` is mostly (if not exclusively) for library authors

Comment: No `double* array` since the late 1990s, this should be `vector<double>`.No `double** ptr`. References can be used instead of pointers. This code has several problems, and `new` is the least. This code can easily result in access violations or buffer overflows

Comment: The `Foo` class contains a pointer to dynamic memory, but does not conform to the [Rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) to manage that memory properly. Also, `Bar()` is outputting a **dangling pointer** to memory that has already been freed by `Foo`'s destructor, so the `printf()` in `main()` is reading from invalid memory and thus exhibits **undefined behavior**.

Comment: I tried with MinGW 8.x, and print out 8.0 for both cases. What is you enviroment?

Comment: In some cases, `printf` can call `malloc`

Comment: I wouldn't waste my time with questions of type "why does this obviously invalid program manifests Undefined Behaviour in this particular way?". They are largely pointless.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. Yes, in hindsight, I think you're probably right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `printf` there could make the compiler rearrange things so they aren't the same as when not calling it, and the value may rest in that memory address for some time, but you can't (and you shouldn't) count on that.

As comments and @Joseph Larson says your construction is a bug.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the life of the objects you're creating.

```
Foo f;
```

This exists within the scope of Bar(), but when Bar() exits, f is destroyed, freeing the buffer you created.

At that point, ptr points to some random memory location that could be used for anything else. You can no longer count on it. You have no idea what's going to be there.

And that's a flat out bug.